Nginx ip configuration issue
I'm trying to deploy my django web site to nginx on my amazon ec2 server but could not succeed so far. I have done all the steps on my local computer and managed to make it work. But when it comes to my server I have tried every possible things that I know but no luck so far. Also when I run python3 manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000 I'm able to access to my website through the amazon ec2 public ip address like http://11.53.22.62:8000/. So probably I have configured something wrong.
The url that I'm trying to access is for example : http://11.53.22.62:8070 (my amazon ec2 public ip)
Here is my configurations:
nginx.conf
events {}

pid /home/ubuntu/projectmicroven/var/nginx.pid;

http {
    error_log /home/ubuntu/projectmicroven/var/nginx.error.log warn;
    access_log /home/ubuntu/projectmicroven/var/nginx.access.log;

    server {
        server_name 11.53.22.62;
        listen 8070;


        root /home/ubuntu/projectmicroven/www/public/;

        location /static/ {
            alias /projectmicroven/www/public/;
            include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
        }

        location / {
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8081;
        }
    }
}

gunicorn.conf.py
workers=2
errorlog="/home/ubuntu/projectmicroven/var/microven.gunicorn.error.log"
accesslog="/home/ubuntu/projectmicroven/var/microven.gunicorn.access.log"
loglevel="debug"

bind =["127.0.0.1:8081"]

Anyone has any idea? Thanks in advance.

Please make sure port 8070 is allowed on Security group on AWS.

thanks for answer but I do want to use nginx rather than "python3 manage.py runserver 127.0.0.1:8000"

This is an additioned option, you can ignore it you want, updated the answer

Thanks. Tried your suggestion but still no luck. Also is there any specific reason for 8080 port? Because with this url (proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8081) I'm refering to gunicorn binding.

you are running your application on port 8080, right ? so proxy_pass should be asigned to this port

please make sure secrutiy group on AWS have allowed this port 8070 accessed from the internet

Thank you very much. I'm new to amazon cloud stuff when I allowed to port 80 thought that system will allowed 8070 as well. Updated security group on AWS  allowed 8070 port and issue have been resolved. If you can put your comment as an answer I can mark it as correct answer thanks.
